# What does the Linux /proc/meminfo "Mapped" topic mean?

Tags: linux, memory, kernel

What does the Linux /proc/meminfo "Mapped" topic mean?  I have seen several one-liners that tell me it is the "Total size of memory in kilobytes that is mapped by devices or libraries with mmap."  But I have now spent almost twenty hours searching the 2.6.30.5 kernel source code trying to confirm this statement, and I have been unable to do so -- indeed I see some things which seem to conflict with it.

The "Mapped" count is held in `global_page_state[NR_FILE_MAPPED]`.  The comment near the declaration of `NR_FILE_MAPPED` says: "Pagecache pages mapped into pagetables. Only modified from process context."

1. Aren't all of the pages referred to by meminfo's "Cached" topic file-backed?  Doesn't that mean that all these pages must be "Mapped"?  I've looked at a few dozen meminfo listings, from several different architectures, and always the "Mapped" value is much smaller than the "Cached" value.
2. At any given time most of memory is filled with executable images and shared libraries.  Looking at /proc/pid/smaps, I see that all of these are mapped into VMAs.  Are all of these mapped into memory using mmap()?  If so, why is "Mapped" so small?  If they aren't mapped into memory using mmap(), how do they get mapped?  Calls on `handle_mm_fault`, which is called by `get_user_pages` and various architecture-dependent page-fault handlers, increment the "Mapped" count, and they seem to do so for any page associated with a VMA.
3. I've looked at the mmap() functions of a bunch of drivers.  Many of these call `vm_insert_page` or `remap_vmalloc_range` to establish their mappings, and these functions do increment the "Mapping" count.  But a good many other drivers seem to call `remap_pfn_range`, which, as far as I can tell, doesn't increment the "Mapping" count.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. It's the other way around.  Everything in Mapped is also in Cached - Mapped is pagecache data that's been mapped into process virtual memory space.  Most pages in Cached are not mapped by processes.
2. The same page can be mapped into many different pagetables - it'll only count in Mapped once, though.  So if you have 100 processes running, each with 2MB mapped from `/lib/i686/cmov/libc-2.7.so`, that'll still only add 2MB to Mapped.

Comment: Ah!  <b>Process</b> memory space.  That may be enough of a clue -- thanks!

Comment: Yes, now that I'm looking for it, I see where callers of `handle_mm_fault`, such as `do_page_fault` in arch/arm, test to see that the fault has a user context.  But aren't all of the pages in the page cache subject to page faulting?

Comment: I believe they should only be subject to write faults, not not-present faults.  But what bearing does this have on the question?

Comment: I would expect any file-backed page to be subject to a not-present fault if it has been paged out, or if it was never fully loaded in the first place.  One of the things that confused me was that `handle_mm_fault` seemed to handle faults against any page.  If it does not handle faults for ordinary file-backed pages, how are such faults handled?

Comment: If it's been paged out it's no longer in the page cache.

Answer (score 0):

I think the intention is that it counts the number of pages that are mapped from files. In my copy of the source (2.6.31), it is incremented in `page_add_file_rmap`, and decremented in `page_remove_rmap` if the page to be removed is not anonymously mapped. `page_add_file_rmap` is, for example, invoked in `__do_fault`, again in case the mapping is not anonymous.

So it looks all consistent to me...